# In mediawiki, Cannot insert pages with bodies longer than the specified value, Why?

Tags: mediawiki

I can not put more than 70,000 bytes of text as a body on the page. I took these steps to solve this problem, but it was not successful:
I am sending a page with more than 70k characters to the server and I have checked this from the **inspect element** that the submitted request is definitely longer than 70k then

1- The end of the request was cut in the first part of the MediaWiki code (index.php) and part of the submitted information was deleted. index.php is the **first part of the code** that starts processing the request after receiving the request in apache

2- I modified the following variables to php.ini on the Apache server but the problem was not solved

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 100
```

**can you help me**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check the value of [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) Apache setting.
- Check the value of [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) PHP setting.
- A [quote](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Common_errors_and_symptoms#Content_Limits) from *MediaWiki* Documentation:

> If your Apache server has the Hardened PHP patch, you may need to edit several variables in your `/etc/php.ini` file if you wish to have wiki pages with large amounts of content. In particular, consider the settings for `varfilter.max_value_length`, `hphp.post.max_value_length`, and `hphp.request.max_value_length`. The default settings may limit your pages to less than 10k or 64k in size.
> Another possibility is if your Apache server is using `mod_security` that could be interfering with mediawiki. You will need to turn it off for mediawiki to work properly

- [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) is not relevant here.
- [`memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) of 1GB is excessive. 128M will usually be enough.